# free: invalid pointer when deleting a dynamically created array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I'm currently practicing pointers arithmetics and I can't figure out why this code ends on a "free(): invalid pointer" error when it comes to executing the last line with `delete [] arr;`.

I realized that the same code runs without any issue when using the program C4Droid on my Android phone (using the compiler "G++ + Bionic") but on my tablet using GCC, it just doesn't work. The only way I found around it is to make sure that the arr array is currently pointing to the first address. The moment it doesn't it seems to fail. I don't know if it SHOULD fail on my phone too or if it's somehow a configuration issue in the IDE I use on my tablet (tried with codeblocks and codelite). Can you please help?

I'm also well aware that I'm initializing values for the two first spots of the array while it's technically possible to choose an array size smaller than this. It's just tests.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int *arr{};
    size_t size{};
    std::cout << "Please enter the size of the array you want to create: "; std::cin >> size;
    arr = new int[size];
    *(arr + 0) = 5;
    *(arr + 1) = 10;
    std::cout << "++arr: " << ++arr << " (pointer incrementation, we move by an int and arr is now arr + 1)" << std::endl;  
    delete [] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I don't know if it SHOULD fail on my phone too" - It's Undefined Behaviour. It can do whatever it wants, including crashing, not crashing, seemingly working correctly, formatting your hard drive or [making demons fly out of your nose](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). You can only `delete` pointer allocated with `new` and nothing else.

Comment: `arr` is not the `arr` that was allocated with `new`, as you incremented the pointer.

Comment: "runs without any issue" should be "runs without any issue *that I could detect*".  There was an issue, but the symptoms under Android were very subtle.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't deleting the same pointer you allocated - `++arr` moved the pointer. Calling `delete[]` on any pointer that wasn't allocated by `new type[]` is undefined behavior - it could work, it could fail catastrophically and it could do anything in between - but you really should **not** rely on it.

Comment: Thanks, all clear kow! I had mistakenly thought that ```delete [] arr``` would still work because ```++arr``` was pointing to the next address in the array I had dynamically allocated. I didn't realize that just by changing the address, even in that case, would mess up the deallocation.

Answer (score 2):

After this statement where you incremented the pointer `arr`

```
std::cout << "++arr: " << ++arr << " (pointer incrementation, we move by an int and arr is now arr + 1)" << std::endl;
```

the pointer now does not have the address of the allocated memory.

So the next statement

```
delete [] arr;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You have to pass to the operator delete [] a pointer with the same value (address) that was returned by the operator new.

You could write for example

```
delete [] --arr;
```

using the decrement operator to reset the pointer to its initial value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That does make a lot of sense now. That means I always have to be sure to keep the original address somewhere in case I ever do pointer arithmetic like this so that I can restore the pointer's value to what it used to be before I summon ```delete [] arr```. This is also why it worked after I 'reset' the pointer to the original address. Good to know!